# Perform operations on Ontology through SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, ontology

I have developed an `ontology` but it is not published yet.
I want to perform different operations on it, `CRUD` mainly, through `SPARQL`.
Is it possible without publishing it?
If yes, please guide how?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit broad and I am not sure what you mean by "publish" your ontology. If you look at the SPARQL documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/), or this code example regarding CRUD operations on RDF sets [here](https://anandavala.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/sparql-update-example-code-for-create-insert-delete-edit/) you will find all the necessary SPARQL syntax to perform the CRUD operations. Or if you want to use HTTP in conjunction with SPARQL and RDF go to this [example](http://callimachusproject.org/docs/1.1/articles/crud-operations-on-rdf-content.docbook?view)
 Now if you are having trouble with using SPARQL with a specific framework, please ask your question with that focus and include your attempted solution.